# number of IIS threads used by a ASP.NET Web API service

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

How can I know the number of IIS threads consumed at a given time by my ASP.NET Web API service?

I can count .NET CLR threads of the running application by the below code snippet:

```
int number = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count;
```

but my question is about IIS threads.

IIS v8.5, Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

In [IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-web-server-overview) a service (ASP.NET application) is running using an [application pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868612/what-is-an-iis-application-pool). So if the name of the application pool is known at runtime, you can determine the number of threads for your application pool:

```
var applicationPoolName = "YOUR APPLICATION POOL";

using (var serverManager = new Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager())
{
    var applicationPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[applicationPoolName];

    var threadsCount = applicationPool
                            .WorkerProcesses
                            .Select(p => Process.GetProcessById(p.ProcessId))
                            .SelectMany(p => p.Threads.Cast<ProcessThread>())
                            .Count();
}
```